# ParseUser query doesn't seem to work in fragments

Tags: android-fragments, parse-platform

I have an application with 5 tabs using bottomNavigationBar and each tab contains a different fragment. I am looking to display a username list on one of the tabs but having difficulty with Parse queries. I can call the new findInBackground method in the main activity in which the fragments are held, but when called in the fragment itself it doesn't seem to work. Appreciate any help

```
public ArrayList<String> getUserList() {

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereNotEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    query.addAscendingOrder("username");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects.size() > 0) {
                    usernames.clear();
                    for (ParseUser user : objects) {
                        usernames.add(user.getUsername());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("size of list - ", " 0 ");

                }
            } else {
                Log.i("Error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    return usernames;
}
```

The list is empty after running this